# How Can I Pass Array in http.request node?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I want pass array in my route POST

I Did try this

my object is

```
var myobj = [{name:'foo',name:'bar',name:'buz'}]
```

and I want pass these values in this http.request

```
var options = {
     hostname    : 'myhost',
     port        : 'myport',
     path        : 'myroute',
     method      : 'POST',
     agent       : false,
     body        : myobj,
     headers     : {'Content-Length': myobj.length}
 };

 var req = http.request(options,function(res) {});

router.post('myroute', function( req, res ){
    //I want myobj here
    console.dir(req.body); //EMPTY
})
```

I did try also

```
path        : 'myroute'+myobj and i recived socket hang up
```

I did try also

```
json = JSON.stringify(docs);
```

Comment: How can you post a body when `Content-Length` is `0`?

Comment: @Bergi I've update...that was old code

Comment: `myobj.length` is `1`. How do you expect the array to be serialized to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
req.write(JSON.stringify(myobj));

router.post('myroute', function( req, res ){
    console.dir(req.body);
})
```